# In GTM, how do I use a CSS Selector on a Click Element trigger?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-firebase

I want to create a "Click Element" trigger with a CSS selector... basically I want to set a trigger on a specific element, rather than all elements. So I create a trigger called "Click - All Elements" and then "Some clicks"... but it asks me to attach a variable to it??

So I tried to create an Auto-Event Variable with type "Element"... but then "element" in the data layer just returns the URL that element links to, rather than the entire element (it's returning "http://example.com/signup", rather than the actual HTML element)

This doesn't make any sense. All I want is to set a trigger on a specific CSS selected element. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

To check for a CSS selector in a trigger, you need to create a variable that looks for your specific CSS selector. To do this, you need a variable called "DOM-element" to specify to your click trigger with the "Some clicks" option.

**Instructions:** 
If you go to the section with variables, click the "NEW"-button to create a new variable. Once the right hand side pans out, open the "Variable configuration" and click on the one called "DOM-element". In the drop-down, you can select CSS-selector. Insert the value you'd like to check for in your trigger, and this should do as you ask.

[image: CSS Selector]

Comment: After creating this how do I actually plug it into the trigger? Because I have to create some equivalence to the variable... i.e DOM Element contains _____.

Comment: You can either fill in your value from CSS selector that is returned, OR, you can actually just use "Click Element" as the variable, and then match it with the CSS selector you'd like to use. I might have misinterpreted your initial question. Please use option #2, as it might better suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm assuming you have multiple elements that have the same class, and yet you only want to target one with your click element trigger? If you can add IDs or data elements instead of just relying on a class, you can still do it using a "Click" event and "matches css selector" in your "Fires On" setting.

So if you had the following element:

`<a id="whatever" href="whatever">My Link</a>`

Since IDs are unique you would just use the following selector "matches css selector":

`#whatever`

With data attribute on specific element, you can target all elements with specific classes, but limit it based on a unique identifier you set in a data attribute:

So if you had the following element:

`<a href="whatever" data-mytrack='4'>My Link</a>`

You would use the following selector for "matches css selector":

`a[data-mytrack='4']`

Comment: Sorry, my question isn't selecting exactly, it's where do I actually do the "matches css selector" in tag manager. I have to connect it to a variable in the trigger, but what should the variable be? I tried making it an auto-event variable and it gave me the content of the element rather than the element itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using like this, and it works.

[Trigger Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSsuY.png)